# Operating an external application through C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to operate an external application through C#, e.g. Winamp. Is it possible just using C#? I can open the application using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`. Then I want to perform some operations on it. Please tell me the way to achieve this.

Comment: Why? Do you want to play mp3 files in your program or automate repeatable operation in winamp itself? In first case you don't even need winamp (but theoretically you can use it or its dll-s, com, .net wrapper, whatever). In second you better use tools specially designed to make *macro*  (to example, [`Autohotkey`](http://www.autohotkey.com/)). So why? What operations do you need and for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will vary from application to application.

Some applications, such as the Microsoft Office suite, expose an extensive class library via COM, which you can use to automate their behaviour.

Others provide nothing! In this case the best you can home for it so simulate user mouse and keyboard activity within the application in order to make it think a user is interacting with it. Take a look at the [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) and the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for how you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky to answer. Some applications do allow external automation and provide some programming interface to communicate with them. Others can be automated by low-level tactics such as mouse clicks and sending key strokes. Similarly you could delve deeper and find HWNDs of screen elements to send Windows Messages to them. Spy++ tool may be of good value for you.